# When is mut required when passing an Option<&mut T>

Tags: rust

I have a function where I need to pass in a struct, do some operations, then push the result into the struct. The struct may or may not exist so I wrap it in an Option before I pass a mutable reference to the function. Simplified it is similar to the below.

It seems there are two different ways that it can be written, and I am trying to understand why the variable a needs to be mutable, even though I am not modifying it directly

```
struct Foo {
    value: Vec<i32>,
}

fn bar(a: Option<&mut Foo>) {
    <do_stuff>
    while <condition> {
    <do_stuff>
        if let Some(&mut ref mut x) = a {
            x.value.push(value);
        }
    }
}
```

In bar &mut needs to be passed into the if let

```
fn bar2(mut a: Option<&mut Foo>) {
    <do_stuff>
    while <condition> {
        <do_stuff>
        if let Some(ref mut x) = a {
            x.value.push(value);
        }
    }
}
```

In bar2 a needs to be defined as mutable in the function declaration

```
fn bar3(a: Option<&mut Foo>){
    if let Some(x) = a {
        x.value.push(0);
    }
}
```

I don't think it has to do with the value inside a being modified, as the same process without the loop (bar3) does not require a to be mutable.

From what I understand, using "ref mut" on the if let statement is supposed to prevent the value inside the Option from moving inside the block. This is required because of the loop. Is the mutability of a also required because of the loop? I am sure there is something going on with dereferencing and re-sharing that I don't understand here.

I realize that there is probably better ways to do this, but I was just messing around trying to better understand how borrowing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that the first code sample works at all, but I'll try to break down the syntax to see how it functions:

- ```
  let a: Option<&mut Foo> = ...;
  if let Some(x) = a {
      x.value.push(0);
  }
  ```

  This works because assigning will *move* the value and transfer ownership to the left-hand side. This does not require the original value to be mutable. In this case, the left-hand side destructures the `Option` into `Some(x)` where `x` is a `&mut Foo`.

---

- ```
  let a: Option<&mut Foo> = ...;
  if let Some(ref mut x) = a {
      x.value.push(0);
  }
  ```

  This will not work without `a` being mutable because it is attempting to mutably reference the `Option`'s inner value (`x` will be `&mut &mut Foo`) and you cannot get a mutable reference to a variable's fields without the variable itself being mutable.

---

- ```
  let a: Option<&mut Foo> = ...;
  if let Some(&mut x) = a {
      x.value.push(0);
  }
  ```

  This isn't one of your examples, but I need to explain it regardless. This will not work. What `&mut` does when destructuring essentially reflects what its matching on. Here, you'd try to match the type `&mut Foo` with the declaration `&mut x`; the `&mut`s cancel out and `x` will be of type `Foo`. This of course fails because you cannot get an owned value from a reference unless it implements `Copy`.

---

- ```
  let a: Option<&mut Foo> = ...;
  if let Some(&mut ref mut x) = a {
      x.value.push(0);
  }
  ```

  This is interesting because I would not expect these rules to interact in this way, but yet here we are. It seems the rule to match `&mut _` is applied first such that `ref mut x` is then matched against a `Foo` value (that isn't moved), which has the effect of declaring `x` as `&mut Foo`. The end result is that the inner value of `a` is *reborrowed* mutably without `a` itself being mutable.

  This is safe only because you have ownership of `a`. If you were to try it with `&Option<&mut Foo>` then you would get an error indicating you can't mutate through a shared reference.

---

If you're looking for an experienced opinion, I'd simply do this and call it a day:

```
let mut a: Option<&mut Foo> = ...;
if let Some(x) = &mut a {
    x.value.push(0);
}
```

This is pretty much the same as your `bar2` sample, but just written a bit differently. The use of `ref`/`ref mut` has *mostly* gone out of fashion since [match ergonomics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md) was introduced which made them mostly unnecessary (except for some obscure cases). Though I will keep this pattern in mind if I ever need it in the future :).

So, *"when is mut required when [using] Option<&mut T>"*? All the non-consuming methods of `Option` that grant mutable access to its inner value (which is required to either use it mutably or reborrow it mutably) need `&mut` access to the `Option`. So the answer is, pretty much always, except you found a case where that isn't true (since it doesn't rely on a function call).